# What is best strategy to multiple turn prisoners dilemma, when your opponents actions are hidden?

Tags: strategy, game, game-theory

Best strategy for multiple turn prisoners dilemma is called [tit for tat](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tit-for-tat.asp) you start with `cooperation` and then repeat your opponents answer from previous turn.

Is there a strategy when your opponents answer is unknown, 
or opponents answer is hidden for some turns?

Should one just go `defect` all the time like in single game scenario, or is there something more clever?

**What is best strategy to multiple turn prisoners dilemma, when your opponents actions are hidden?**

Answer (score 2):

Because your opponent's actions are hidden, you have no previous information to base your next action on. This means that you're always in a situation similar to the first round of the regular iterative prisoner's dilemma (or a prisoner's dilemma with only one round).

In the scenario that only one round is being played, it benefits player A to always defect, as this results in the best case scenario regardless of what player B picks.

The reason tit-for-tat works is that there is motivation to co-operate, as both players co-operating has a larger benefit that both players defecting. But in an iterative game with no feedback, defecting every turn is the dominant strategy.